# How does AirBnB display degrees of separation between FB connect users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to achieve something like AirBnB's facebook friends of friends data, displayed on all it's apartment listings. See attached images to see what i mean. My research on Stack Exchange so far suggests it's not possible, i.e.  [Facebook - get friends of friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118318/facebook-get-friends-of-friends)

...yet AirBnB are doing it. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Look above each apartment listing:
[image: AirBnB search results page]
Look at the box on the right - You and Sebastian (Sebastian is not known to me but the friends in the list are)
[image: Apartment listing page on AirBnB]

Comment: Is this just a "these other people are also using the site" type of feature ?

Comment: I don't think so - AirBnB is able to tell you which of your friends is also friends of the specific host for each apartment/room in its database. I.e. it is looking at your friends list, looking at the host's friends and pulling out the matches - something I thought FB did not allow...https://www.airbnb.com/social

Comment: they are probably not asking facebook for that information. they are probably requestion your friends list and the other users list and comparing it themselves.

Comment: Facebook themselves suggest it is done using the graph api (which does not invalidate your point, they may still be storing the entire friend list and comparing themselves): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/showcase/airbnb/

Comment: idk ... is there still offline access permission in facebook ?

Comment: they removed it and replaced it with long life access tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

Comment: _“it is looking at your friends list, looking at the host's friends and pulling out the matches - something I thought FB did not allow”_ – what makes you think that …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using Facebook Login to request the friends list of each user and store them locally. I guess that they then are able to query their database similar to

1. Get the list of friends of the host
2. Compare the list of friends of the host to the list of friends of the actual user
3. Show matches